# Read Internet Explorer console output with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, logging

I'm working on testing automation in Internet Explorer 11 with Selenium and I'm looking to read any console output for errors. However, any research I pulled up lead to a 2 year old response saying that the IE driver doesn't support reading logs of any kind ([see here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/468)). Has there been any update to this issue? If not, is there any workaround to reading JS errors in IE with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no change to the log API not being implemented in the IE driver. One reason for this is the arrival of the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html), which does not define any logging end points. Moreover, even if the driver were to implement the logging API, getting the console log in IE would still be impossible, since Internet Explorer does not provide any programmatic access to its debugging tools.

One approach to capturing JavaScript errors in IE is to set `window.onerror` and read any errors that occur there. Of course, this will not retrieve any JavaScript errors that occur during onLoad, or before the error handler is attached to the onError event. To accomplish that, another approach I've seen used is to use a proxy to inject the event handler script into the page before it gets to the browser. [This blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html) shows an example of how to do that. Even though the example is written in C#, the same technique can be applied in any of the other language bindings.